# Is there a better way to avoid duplicate lifecycle callbacks?

Tags: node.js, sails.js, waterline

Waterline allows for some lifecycle callbacks on models as listed below...

- beforeValidation / *fn(values, cb)*
- beforeCreate / *fn(values, cb)*
- afterCreate / *fn(newlyInsertedRecord, cb)*
- beforeValidation / *fn(valuesToUpdate, cb)*
- beforeUpdate / *fn(valuesToUpdate, cb)*
- afterUpdate / *fn(updatedRecord, cb)*
- beforeDestroy / *fn(criteria, cb)*
- afterDestroy / *fn(cb)*

However, what if I want to take action before create and update?

Rails had a `beforeSave` which was great for this. Is there something similar in sails.js?

I could have both callbacks call a function, but I want to be sure there isn't a better way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can call `beforeUpdate` from `beforeCreate`, or vice versa:

```
beforeCreate: function(values, cb) {
    // Forward to the model's beforeUpdate method
    return User.beforeUpdate(values, cb);
},

beforeUpdate: function(valuesToUpdate, cb) {
    ...
}
```

Just keep in mind that the values sent via an `update` call will likely be different than the ones sent to `create`; for instance, don't rely on an instance's `id` value being available!

Comment: Thanks Scott, are there any plans to add some of the other "Rails" style callbacks like `save`?